# End key on laptop types the number 1 instead of moving cursor

Tags: keyboard

I've run into a problem with a new laptop where the `End` key doesn't work properly. Instead of moving the cursor to the end of the line it just types `1` where the cursor is. The behavior is the same in different software applications.

The on-screen keyboard `End` key and an external keyboard `End` key both function properly, moving the cursor.

Device: Dell XPS 13 2-in-1, Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

After a keyboard replacement that didn't make a difference and some more digging around online, unintuitive solution is to **turn off Num Lock.**

For some reason the `End` key on the laptop is registered as the `(1, End)` key from a numpad. When Num Lock is off, the key is `End`. However, when Num Lock is on it types `1` like you want on a 10-key layout. It is unintuitive that this is the problem for a few reasons, and these demonstrate some other fixes to make to keep this from happening in the future:

- There is no `Num Lock` key, or even secondary 10-key layout on the laptop, so it is not clear when Num Lock is on from the laptop alone. If you are using an external keyboard you may be able to see from the indicator light. *First, try to remember to turn off Num Lock before disconnecting.*
- If you forget, and disconnect, there is no `Num Lock` key to press later. You can *use the on-screen keyboard to toggle Num Lock but it is hidden.* In the on-screen keyboard choose Options, then turn on the numpad display.
- I believe the bios default is to turn on Num Lock when you turn the computer on, perpetuating the problem. To *change this bios default for Num Lock* you need to restart the computer through these steps (from [here](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/access-bios-windows-10)):

  - Go to Windows Settings - Update and Recovery - Recovery (on the left menu) - Restart Now.
  - Then choose Advanced Settings - Troubleshoot - Advanced Options - UEFI Firmware Settings
  - Once you are there, find the boot defaults and switch the Num Lock startup setting.

As a more advanced solution I played with [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) to add a `Num Lock` key to the keyboard by remapping my `F9` key to `Num Lock`. Now I have a physical way to toggle Num Lock instead of the on-screen keyboard. (But, when I tried to change the `(1, End)` key on my laptop to a plain old `End` key, it broke the external keyboard 10-key, so that wasn't an option.)

Comment: Ah Dell, who needs num lock, facepalm!